# Draw centerline of road polygon in Python

Tags: python, postgis, geometry

I'm trying to draw a center-line of this road element but I'm not able to make it with the PostGIS function ST_ApproximateMedialAxis()

Also tried the python centerline library but it giving me error

Code:

```
    for key in list(self.dct_polygons.keys()):
        poly_geom = self.dct_polygons[key]
        centerlineObj = Centerline.Centerline(poly_geom, self.dist)
        self.dct_centerlines[key] = centerlineObj.createCenterline()
```

Error:

```
vor = Voronoi(border)
File "qhull.pyx", line 2494, in scipy.spatial.qhull.Voronoi.__init__
File "qhull.pyx", line 354, in scipy.spatial.qhull._Qhull.__init__
scipy.spatial.qhull.QhullError: QH6154 Qhull precision error: Initial 
simplex is flat (facet 1 is coplanar with the interior point)
```

For the below polygon this is not working

[image]
Even for few polygons I have been able to draw centerlines but which was not up to mark.

[image]

Comment: Are you saying that it works for all of your other polygons, but just not the complex red one?

Comment: yup work for some polygons but failing for complex one

Comment: There is something wrong with your geometry. My guess is that it is near the "rounded" corner near the intersection of the two roads. It looks like it may be drawn incorrectly. Try ST_MakeValid first. Or redraw your polygon. Possibly self-intersections.

Comment: I have tried ST_MakeValid as well  but after running it giving me following error 
**ERROR:  straight skeleton of Polygon with touching interior rings is not implemented**